# I could close vote 2 times on a post

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close

Today I saw [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27548721/swift-how-to-draw-a-circle-from-the-center-of-a-label) and voted to close as *unclear what you're asking*. It was the first close vote on that post.

Later in the day I made some reviews in LQ queue and the same post pops up as a review. Again, I voted to close on that post. This time I was the 5th so the post gets closed.

The list of voters shows the first voter's name (which was me) as *Display name is missing*

Is this a bug? I think the same post should not be presented as a review for someone who already flagged it.

[image]

Comment: Is this you: http://stackoverflow.com/users/2092358/display-name-is-missing - if you clicked the link, you would have seen that it isn't you (or you have 2 different accounts).

Comment: Pretty sure the devs of SO would be able to come up with some better alternative to `Display Name is missing` for a null/bugg-ish value.

Comment: I'm still a little curious how you made it to that assumption. Had you seen a similar question previously and thought you were seeing the same one again, or was it solely the misleading display name of that user?

Comment: @animuson: Sorry for the confusion. I made a downvote earlier that day. I thought it was a close vote so I assumed I could close vote 2 times. My fault. The misleading user name did the rest ;-)

Answer (score 6):

That link is showing you the actual name for another user, not replacing your own name:

[image: profile for Display Name is missing on Stack Exchange, a network of free, community-driven Q&A sites]

The review is showing up in [your activity profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3845091/zisoft?tab=activity&sort=reviews) but votes are private; you might check your own activity profile to confirm that you did indeed VTC the same post prior to reviewing.

Comment: Argh :-) I see. The user name was pretty misleading, though. Thanks!

Comment: You are right, I made a downvote earlier the day, not a close vote. Sorry for the confusion, it was my fault